# ggplot gridded SpatialPolygonsDataFrame producing odd triangles and subsetting data based on point data

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, raster, r-sp

Using the code below I can plot the following:
This code is adapted from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210092/plotting-square-grids-on-a-map-and-extracting-each-grid-information-using-r)

[image]

As you can see there are  few issues with the plot. I am struggling to

1. Remove weird lines in plot
2. Only plot cells (grids) where there are data
3. Plot ID (see `gridSpatialPolygons$values`) on top of the grid cell

I realise there are a few points to this question but I hope one solution solves all.

```
# Load libraries
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

# Projection
wgs.84 <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")

# Load data
x <- c(76.82973, 76.82972, 76.82969, 76.83076, 76.83075, 76.83071, 76.83129, 76.83126, 76.83125) 
y <- c(28.26734, 28.26644, 28.26508, 28.26778, 28.26733, 28.26507, 28.26912, 28.26732, 28.26687) 
z <- c(-56.7879, -58.22462, -58.4211, -55.75333, -58.55153, -56.38619, -56.11011, -58.17415, -59.77212)

# Create data frame
dataset <- data.frame("LONGITUDE" = x, "LATITUDE" = y, "VALUES" = z)

# Create SpatialPointsDataFrame object  
datasetSP <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = dataset[,c(1,2)], data = data.frame("id" = 1:nrow(dataset), "values" = dataset$VALUES), proj4string = wgs.84)

# Extent
extentDatasetSP <-extent(datasetSP)

# Make grid options

# Cell size (map units)
xCellSizeGrid <- 0.001
yCellSizeGrid <- 0.001

# Grid
grid <- GridTopology(cellcentre.offset = c(extentDatasetSP@xmin, extentDatasetSP@ymin),
                     cellsize = c(xCellSizeGrid, yCellSizeGrid), 
                     cells.dim = c(3, 7))

# Create SpatialGrid object
gridSpatial <- SpatialGrid(grid = grid, proj4string = wgs.84)


# Convert to SpatialPixels object
gridSpatialPixels <- as(gridSpatial, "SpatialPixels")

# Convert to SpatialPolygons object
gridSpatialPolygons <- as(gridSpatialPixels, "SpatialPolygons")

# Add 'id' and 'values' to every polygon
gridSpatialPolygons$id <- 1:nrow(coordinates(gridSpatialPolygons))
gridSpatialPolygons$values <- paste("Gridvalue", 1:nrow(coordinates(gridSpatialPolygons)), sep = ":")

# Get attributes from polygons 
samplePointsInPolygons2 <- datasetSP %over% gridSpatialPolygons

ggplot(gridSpatialPolygons, aes(x = long, y = lat)) + 
  geom_polygon(color = "red") +
  geom_point(data = dataset,
             aes(x = LONGITUDE,
                 y = LATITUDE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to spatial objects, `ggplot2` (and tidyverse in general) seems to play nicer with `sf` than `sp`. The advice below is taken from one of the help files in the associated `broom` package:

> Note that the `sf` package now defines tidy spatial objects and is the
> recommended approach to spatial data. `sp` tidiers are likely to be
> deprecated in the near future in favor of `sf::st_as_sf()`. Development
> of `sp` tidiers has halted in `broom`.

Things should be fairly straightforward after conversion to `sf`.

```
library(dplyr)

sf::st_as_sf(gridSpatialPolygons) %>%
  filter(id %in% samplePointsInPolygons2$id) %>%       # keep only grid cells with data 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(colour = "red") +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = values),                    # label cells 
               nudge_y = 0.0003, colour = "grey40") +
  geom_point(data = dataset,
             aes(x = LONGITUDE,
                 y = LATITUDE))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Fantastic - thank you for the explanation. It takes quite a while with the real data but it works a treat. Many thanks! Hours (and stress!) pouring into this problem just dissolved!